# How make background animation?

Tags: android, android-animation

I have `LinearLayout` and I want create `animation` for it. I need some help for creating `animation`.

***It is my background:***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<inset xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:insetLeft="-2dp"
    android:insetRight="-2dp"
    android:insetTop="-2dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <stroke
            android:width="1.25dp"
            android:color="#ffffff" />
        <solid android:color="#00000000" />
    </shape>
</inset>
```

It looks like `(black - ground, white and purpul - background):`

[image]

***But I want this:***

[image]

When `animation` start green line begin should stretched in both directions

I tried this:

```
TransitionDrawable transition = (TransitionDrawable) emailBg.getBackground();
        transition.startTransition(5000);
```

but it is not working

Comment: http://flavienlaurent.com/blog/2013/08/05/make-your-background-moving-like-on-play-music-app/